# Building Android Wear app on Eclipse with API>24

Tags: android, eclipse

I need to use Eclipse because of some work conditions. And I want to build something for Wear OS (Android wear) 
So I read this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@tangtungai/how-to-develop-and-package-android-wear-app-using-eclipse-ef1b34126a5d

But it uses old API (4.4W)

is there a way to develop Wearable apps on a more recent API with Eclipse ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its not possible. Starting from Nov 2016 (release of Android Studio 2.2), [Google has officially](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/support-ended-for-eclipse-android.html?m=1) ended support for Eclipse. If you want to develop for latest APIs you need to use Android Studio.

Comment: officially you are correct. But on Eclipse I can build for any API for mobile. why not wearable ?

Answer (score 0):

Google has officially ended support for Eclipse but I can still develop Android apps on Eclipse (even Oreo 8.1) , just could not find how to do that for Wear OS.

So there must be a way to do it. No ?